# how to change date-picker's default Day of week in odoo?

Tags: web, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

Currently in odoo date picker shows from Su-Mo-Tu-We-Th-Fr-Sa
i want to make it starts from Mo-Tu-We-Th-Fr-Sa-Su in some case and in some case Su-Mo-Tu-We-Th-Fr-Sa.
can anyone help me how to achive this 
as i checked in default odoo 12 addons it is hard coded.
web/static/lib/moment/locale/.. language wise different files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[![Solution for you]

[image]

Just try code like this and get solution for your question.
I just try in my local but you have to check that it is not affect on any other functionality of odoo default.

Comment: this will be  hard-coded
now suppose if someone has weekdays from Sun to Sat ?
and in odoo 12 there is one option in languages First day of week it will affects only on calendar views

Comment: Yes Jack I checked that it's affect on calendar view. but it also affect on date or date-time fields.In date or date-time selection you got what you want.

Comment: this need to be done as configurable like odoo-12 language has options.
and above code you shows is in private function is it possible to access private functions.:)?